# Analytic branches of $log(z)$ - where is each one defined?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be the ***analytic*** branch of $\log(z)$ satisfying $f(1)=-2\pi i $. Where is this branch defined?

If $Log(z)$ represents the principal part of $\log$, defined for $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$, it seems that $f(z)=Log(z)-2\pi i$. But does taking the difference affect where is the branch defined?

Since $f(z)=Log(z)-2\pi i$, I would say that the new branch should be defined in $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$. On the other hand, given the value of $f$ at $z=1$, I think $f$ should be defined in $\mathbb{C}-\{ iy| y\leq 0  \}$. Which one is the correct one? Will be happy if you will be able to elaborate.

Thank you

EDIT: my misunderstanding is part of the following question:

> Specify the value of g(ei), where $g$ is the analytic branch of $z^i$, defined in $\{ \mathbb{C}−{iy|y≤0}\} $ , where $g(1)=e^{2π}$.

As $g(z)=e^{i\log(z)}$, we should choose that branch $f$ of $\log$ the I defined above. But since $f(z)=Log(z)-2\pi i$, why it is defined in $\{ \mathbb{C}−{iy|y≤0}\} $ rather than in $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$?
My misunderstanding here comes from some basic properties of analytic branches that I can't figure out. Hope you'll be able to help me out with this.

Comment: DO you mean $log (1)=-2\pi i$?

Comment: fixed it. Thank you Kavi

Comment: The question is unclear.  If you have any analytic branch of the logarithm on any domain then you can add/substract a multiple of $2 \pi i$ so that $f(1)=-2\pi i$ is satisfied.

Comment: The question makes no sense, since there are infinitely many branches $f$ of the logarithm such that $f(1)=-2\pi i$.

Comment: This is exactly the point that I can't understand. In order for the branch to be analytic, shouldn't the domain of definition be explicitly defined?

Comment: Where does the question come from? Is it from a book, lecture notes, exercise or homework? Is there any surrounding context that might make the question more clear?

Comment: The question I mentioned is part of another problem. I hoped that this short version will specify my exact point of misunderstanding.  The full version is to specify the value of $f(ei)$, where $f$ is the analytic branch of $z^i$, defined in $\mathbb{C}-\{ iy| y\leq 0  \}$ , where $f(1)=e^{2\pi}$. Given what I wrote in the original post, I wasn't sure how could this function be defined in $\mathbb{C}-\{ iy| y\leq 0  \}$. I am also editing the original post to make it clearler. Thank you!

Comment: I also edited my original message, which I hope clarifies my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that branches of the logarithm (which is the same as of the argument) are defined on the plane excluding any Jordan arc connecting zero to infinity, so what you need is the argument of $ei$ hence of $i$ when the argument of $1$ is $-2\pi$ and you avoid the negative imaginary line, so go counterclockwise.

Now $\arg i -\arg 1=\pi/2$ if you go counterclockwise from to $1$ to $i$ in your domain and do not need to cross the real axis again (if instead of a simple ray like here, you would exclude a spiral for example, you may need to cross the real axis a few times before you get to $i$ from $1$) so $\arg i = -3\pi/2$ here hence $$z^{ei}=e^{i\log(ei)}=e^{i(\log |ei|+i\arg {ei})}=e^{i(1-3i\pi/2)}=e^{3\pi/2}(\cos 1+i \sin 1)$$

Comment: Thank you Conrad! Will you please elaborate on what would have happen if the ray cut was between $1$ and $i$?

Comment: If you cut a ray at angle $\pi/4$ say, then from $1$ to $i$ you go clockwise the "long way" through the fourth, third and second quadrants, so if you start with argument zero at $1$, you get argument $-\pi/2$ at $-i$ etc so at $i$ the argument is $-3\pi/2$